# Changing publish date does not update post order

Tags: posts

I have a ton of posts which display in descending order by date on my home page. I wanted to re-order them so I edited the publish date on some of them. However, my order of posts on the home page appears to be the same. Shouldn't it update the order since I changed the post dates?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it should, are you using a cache plugin like wp-super cache (or another?)

Comment: no, i'm not. no plugins so it's wierd

Comment: Can you post the code from your index.php or home.php to pastebin

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NPSUTuq8

Comment: Also, I tried this without the pagination and got the same results.

Comment: Yes this is weird. No custom query that could be effecting the order, no plugins or caching software...  Is the pastebin file your index.php or home.php? Under Settings>Reading is the front page set to show your latest posts or a static page? Can you tell me the name of the theme and a link to its home online

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier pursue for posts order using the [Post Types Order](http://www.nsp-code.com/wordpress-plugins/post-types-order) just drag and drop and you're done.